# Java Runtime error Non-Zero Exit Exception (NZEC)

Tags: java

I am getting runtime error (NZEC) on codechef for this code.
But when I used BufferedReader instead of Scanner, my solution got accepted.

```
import java.util.*;
class DiscrepanciesInTheVotersList
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n1 = inp.nextInt();
        int n2 = inp.nextInt();
        int n3 = inp.nextInt();
        int[] a1 = new int[n1];
        int[] a2 = new int[n2];
        int[] a3 = new int[n3];
        for(int i=0;i<n1;i++) a1[i] = inp.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<n2;i++) a2[i] = inp.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<n3;i++) a3[i] = inp.nextInt();
        int[] a = new int[50000];
        for(int i=0;i<n1;i++) a[a1[i]]++;
        for(int i=0;i<n2;i++) a[a2[i]]++;
        for(int i=0;i<n3;i++) a[a3[i]]++;
        ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0;i<50000;i++)
        {
            if(a[i] > 1) al.add(i);
        }
        int m = al.size();
        System.out.println(m);
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++) System.out.println(al.get(i));
    }
}
```

Could you please tell me where am I going wrong.

Comment: What is the code expected to do? What is the expected result?

Comment: What is the input you are passing it?

Comment: It sounds like they want a System.exit(0); as the last line in main().

Comment: @KevinHooke Here's the question:
https://www.codechef.com/problems/VOTERS
You are given 3 lists with ID numbers. You are required to make a final list which should contain ID numbers which appeared in at least 2 lists.
The expected output should be the number of voters in the final list.

Comment: See comment from @stdunbar - please review the guidelines here for acceptable type of questions to ask on SO : http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic